# can't figure out why the layout is not corrent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a calendar webpage. before the insertion of  newly created element by javascript, the layout is fine. but after add the javascript code, the numbers in the first row start to acting weird. I can't figure out why. here is the code.

[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rapcP.png)

```js
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDate = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDate = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

var firstDay = firstDate.getDay();

var days  = document.querySelector(".days");
for (var i = 0; i < helper(firstDay); i++){
   var spaceContainer = document.createElement('LI');
   var spaceholder = document.createTextNode(" ");
   spaceContainer.appendChild(spaceholder); 
   days.insertBefore(spaceContainer, days.firstChild);
}


// get the number right 
function helper(n){
 if (n === 0){
  return 6;
 } else {
  return n - 1;
 }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}

.month {
    padding: 70px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
}

.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.weekdays li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.days {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
}

.days li .active {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white !important
}

/* Add media queries for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
    .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Calendar</h1>

<div class="month">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">❮</li>
    <li class="next">❯</li>
    <li style="text-align:center">
      August<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="weekdays">
  <li>Mo</li>
  <li>Tu</li>
  <li>We</li>
  <li>Th</li>
  <li>Fr</li>
  <li>Sa</li>
  <li>Su</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the `display: inline-block;` you use on list items and in the first row you have li items without text.
I suggest you to try to use `float: left;` and in this case do not forget about clearfix. Bear in mind that you will need to use float and clearfix for weekend items too, so you will have them properly aligned.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgGgLV)

As another option, you may want to try and use flexbox. Here is another [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGJpWB)

No clerfix is needed in this case. Just remove `display: inline-block` from your ul with the class weekdays and class days and apply these styles to you existing code.

```
    .days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.weekdays  {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `inline-block` on list items. This style `inline-block` creates some extra space. There are many ways to remove this space.

One way is to set `font-size: 0` and `letter-spacing: -4px` on parent and reset on children as shown below.

```
.days {
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.days li {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```js
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDate = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDate = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

var firstDay = firstDate.getDay();

var days  = document.querySelector(".days");
for (var i = 0; i < helper(firstDay); i++){
   var spaceContainer = document.createElement('LI');
   var spaceholder = document.createTextNode(" ");
   spaceContainer.appendChild(spaceholder); 
   days.insertBefore(spaceContainer, days.firstChild);
}


// get the number right 
function helper(n){
 if (n === 0){
  return 6;
 } else {
  return n - 1;
 }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}

.month {
    padding: 70px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
}

.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.weekdays li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.days {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    width: 13.6%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
}

.days li .active {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white !important
}

/* Add media queries for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
    .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Calendar</h1>

<div class="month">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">❮</li>
    <li class="next">❯</li>
    <li style="text-align:center">
      August<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="weekdays">
  <li>Mo</li>
  <li>Tu</li>
  <li>We</li>
  <li>Th</li>
  <li>Fr</li>
  <li>Sa</li>
  <li>Su</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `display: inline-block` with `float:left` and add a `clearfix` class to the `ul`

```js
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDate = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDate = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

var firstDay = firstDate.getDay();

var days  = document.querySelector(".days");
for (var i = 0; i < helper(firstDay); i++){
   var spaceContainer = document.createElement('LI');
   var spaceholder = document.createTextNode(" ");
   spaceContainer.appendChild(spaceholder); 
   days.insertBefore(spaceContainer, days.firstChild);
}


// get the number right 
function helper(n){
 if (n === 0){
  return 6;
 } else {
  return n - 1;
 }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}

.month {
    padding: 70px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
}

.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.weekdays li {
    float: left;
    width: 13.6%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.days {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 13.6%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
}

.clearfix:after {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   font-size: 0;
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
}

.days li .active {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white !important
}

/* Add media queries for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
    .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Calendar</h1>

<div class="month">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">❮</li>
    <li class="next">❯</li>
    <li style="text-align:center">
      August<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="weekdays clearfix">
  <li>Mo</li>
  <li>Tu</li>
  <li>We</li>
  <li>Th</li>
  <li>Fr</li>
  <li>Sa</li>
  <li>Su</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days clearfix">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
</ul>
```